# Can't install Mysql for Visual Studio 1.2.7

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, mysql-connector, edmx

Hi everyone and thanks to take the time to see my question.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise, and the installation of MySQL for Visual Studio (with the MySQL installer and the standalone installer) fails at 90%

I tried to do [this](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=85908&thanks=3&notify=195) workaround  (the installation from the Mysql Installer became possible) but the installation is still rolling back at the end of the installation process with the two ways of installing.

Please help, I'm struggling to Update my Model from my Database since 3 days :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was the issue. I had installed visual studio on an other Hard Disk than C:, and the MySQL installer couldn't find the path. Stupid me.

Comment: I have the same issue despite Visual Studio being installed on the same disk as the one I am trying to install MySQL for Visual Studio

Comment: Sorry, but that ain't "stupid you"; that's "stupid installer" for not being able to recognize this normal scenario.